# Component definition is missing display nameeslintreact/display-name

Tags: next.js

I have the following Component in my NextJs app

```
const Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <input {...props} />)
```

All I keep getting as error is

```
Component definition is missing display nameeslintreact/display-name
```

What is possibly the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `anonymous` arrow function to create the component. If you use a regular function you won't get that error.

```
const Input = React.forwardRef(function Input(props, ref) { return <input {...props} />})
```

Or you can just add `displayName` to `Input` const

```
Input.displayName = 'Input'
```